# Can I have more control on zone offset formatting at DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime-format

Currently we are using

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
```

To format the time range to an external vendor for a range of data, for India, that formatter will give time like this:

2018-04-26T00:00:00.000+0530

However, my vendor say they cannot accept this format and it have to look like

2018-04-26T00:00:00.000+05:30

However, look like in DateTimeFormatter, whatever I choose Z/z/X/x, I don't get that format of offset. Just wonder is that a way to customize the offset to be HH:mm?

Or, I need to get the offset in second and work that our myself?

Comment: Use [my answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49032221/5772882), please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is three x. Just tried with [JavaRepl](http://www.javarepl.com/term.html):

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx")
    .withZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .format(java.time.Instant.now())
```

Results in

```
java.lang.String res10 = "2018-04-27T11:06:50.648+00:00"
```

After some trial and error, I saw that this is also documented in the API documentation of `DateTimeFormatter` but it is not easy to find (buried in a lot of other text):

> Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'

[DateTimeFormatter API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: It can be `XXX` also.