# Not able to convert the string to date on Android

Tags: java, android, datetime-parsing, parseexception

I have obtained a string from an API in form of 2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00
How do i convert it into date of format "2017-04-23T19:47:39-0000"?

I tried the following but it gave ParseException

```
String created_at_string = "2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date created_at = sdf.parse(created_at_string);
```

Exception:

```
06-22 18:18:32.517 10396-10396/com.harit.abs W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""2018-04-29T10:55:37+00:00""
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:358)
        at com.harit.abs.Sync_Activity.bu(Sync_Activity.java:169)
        at com.harit.abs.Sync_Activity$2.onCompleted(Sync_Activity.java:118)
        at com.harit.abs.Sync_Activity$2.onCompleted(Sync_Activity.java:87)
        at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:107)
        at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:141)
        at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:128)
        at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:246)
        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:60)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Tried what is given in [SimpleDateFormat with TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747467/simpledateformat-with-timezone)
Still getting the same parse Exception

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
String created_at_string = "2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00";
Date created_at = sdf.parse(created_at_string);
```

Comment: Show the full message of the exception.

Comment: see other answers of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747467/simpledateformat-with-timezone

Comment: Please consider to move from the old and outdated `Date` classes to the more modern `LocalDateTime`, etc. alternatives... Here you could simply use a `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz");`.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: please unmark as duplicate

Comment: @Ben can u please tell me how to use your method

Comment: I recommen you to read this introductory article by oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: Look at your format specifically `+00:00` this means if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversionit will show you that `X` is the one you need not `Z` so it should be `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX");`

Comment: @Ben Agree except `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use, we’ll need an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @OleV.V. sure, I never mentioned to use it, I just named it as an example of the Date and Time API's :)

Comment: anyone familiar with greenDao?

Comment: @Ben ?/ familiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don’t need to

The conversion you are asking about could easily be superfluous. You are asking for a string like `2017-04-23T19:47:39-0000`. This string is in ISO 8601 format, the international standard format. So depending on your exact situation I would expect a string in ISO 8601 to be fine for you. The string you already got, `2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00` is in ISO 8601 too! The standard allows for some variations, and one of them is that the colon in the offset is optional. So the first thing I think that you should do is to pass on the string you get and see if that works. In case it doesn’t, read on.

### java.time

Your desired conversion goes *so* smoothly with `java.time` the modern Java date and time API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatterWithoutColon 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxx");
    String createdAtString = "2017-04-23T19:47:39+00:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(createdAtString);
    String inDesiredFormat = dateTime.format(formatterWithoutColon);
    System.out.println(inDesiredFormat);
```

This prints the desired:

> 2017-04-23T19:47:39+0000

Please note that we didn’t even need a formatter for parsing the string. `OffsetDateTime` and many other classes of `java.time` parse ISO 8601 as their default. Since our requirements for the result are a bit more precise, we use a formatter here. `xx` gives us the offset without colon, for example `+0000`.

The `Date` class that you used is long outdated. So is `SimpleDateFormat`, and it’s notoriously troublesome too. I suggest you avoid those classes.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### The hack

The change you require is very simple, you just want a colon removed. So another, not so nice, but basic and simple solution that doesn’t require ThreeTenABP is a regular expression:

```
    String inDesiredFormat = createdAtString.replaceFirst("([+-]\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$", "$1$2");
```

This gives the same result as above.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could try to set the locale,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how that is supposed to answer the question or parse the input?